# Java or Python way to extract a sub-XML from big XML depending on child text nodes

Tags: java, python, xml, minidom, xmldom

I have a big XML to be handled, I need to extract all "Situation" TAGS if these ones have <_0:roadNumber>A-52, <_0:roadNumber>AP-9 or <_0:roadNumber>A-55 values in theirs, because I don`t need the rest of XML. Then build a XML document with the XML substraction. I don´t need a implementation, only I would like to know how can I handle this or wich API is the most appropiated, thanks.

**PD:** My finall achieve is to dump the XML in a data base

**XML GET:**

```
print("GETTING XML...")
resp = requests.get('http://infocar.dgt.es/datex2/dgt/SituationPublication/all/content.xml', stream = True) #XML that I need
if resp.status_code != 200:
    raise ApiError('GET /tasks/ {}'.format(resp.status_code))
print("XML RECIBIDO 200 OK")
#resp.raw.decode_content = True
print("GUARDANDO XML")
with open("DGT_DATEX.xml", "wb") as handle:
    for data in (resp.iter_content()):
        handle.write(data)

dom = parse("DGT_DATEX.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

For really big XML documents you should best use [SAX](http://www.saxproject.org/) for streaming (not needing to have the full document in memory at once) but for finding elements easly [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is really helpful.

For Python you have some [XPath support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support) in [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and SAX in [xml.sax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.html) - but there of course are other parsers, too.

There are SAX implementations and XPath for Java, too.